# Slik carousel displaying empty slides instead looping them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I code exactly how in examples but my slider behaves differently.

Why this carousel doesn't show slides like: 
#div5 #div6 #div1 -> #div6 #div1 #div2

...instead it's like #div6 #empty #empty

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
        <style>
            #div1 {
                background-color: black;
            }
            #div2 {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            #div3 {
                background-color: #6C9FBB;
            }
            #div4 {
                background-color: #666;
            }
            #div5 {
                background-color: #92C03A;
            }
            #div6 {
                background-color: aqua;
            }
            .element {
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
            }
            .chuj {
                width: 200px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chuj">
            <div><div id="div1" class="element"></div></div>
            <div><div id="div2" class="element"></div></div>
            <div><div id="div3" class="element"></div></div>
            <div><div id="div4" class="element"></div></div>
            <div><div id="div5" class="element"></div></div>
            <div><div id="div6" class="element"></div></div>
        </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.chuj').slick({
                slidesToShow: 3,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 1000,
                infinite: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                arrows: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tomekmularczyk/8740cqvq/

In picture below there is only aqua colored div visible. I would like to see then black and blue.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it appears to be working on my end.  Have you cleared your cache recently?

Comment: I just opened with different browser and still the same. I'll also include a picture in a moment.

Comment: My guess is that it could be because you have a set number on slidesToShow.  Set that to 1 instead of 3 for testing.  Another thing could be that you do not have a wrapper class.  Create a demo via jsFiddle and provide us the link please.

Comment: @Michael https://jsfiddle.net/tomekmularczyk/8740cqvq/ I want 3 slides to be visible.